# date problem in php

Tags: php, mysql

In my php application I have this code:

```
<?php echo date("d/m/ Y ",strtotime($row["m_date"]));?>
```

In it, `$row["m_date"]` is fetching from a database.

The problem is that all the dates are printing perfectly except `27/2/2011`. It's printing `1/1/1970` instead.

The date in the database is fine, and prints correctly in a PDF.

Comment: Please show us the code and the generated html or text or such.

Comment: what is your database field structure?

Comment: are you storing the date in the database as a timestamp or datetime?

Comment: Please do a `var_dump` of `$row["m_date"]` and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 5):

I'll assume you're getting the date from the database as the string `27/2/2011` because that's most probably what happens (correct me if I'm wrong).

PHP considers the string `27/2/2011` as being in the `m/d/Y` format, not `d/m/Y` and tries to parse under that assumption. Because the date is not valid under that format `strtotime` returns `false`. Giving `false` as the timestamp parameter to `date` is taken as `0`, which is the timestamp for January 1st 1970.

What you need to do is either get your date in another format (or better still, as a timestamp) from the database, or parse it yourself (say using `explode`).

Good luck,
Alin

Answer (score 4):

The database should be able to return the date to you as a UNIX timestamp.  For example, MySQL has the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_column) FROM table;
```

Postgres has date_part

```
SELECT DATE_PART('epoch', date_column) FROM table;
```

Most other databases should have similar features.  If you can get the date out as a UNIX time stamp you can pass that directly to date() without having to use strtotime() as well.

All of this does of course assume you're using a temporal datatype for the columns in question (timestamp, datetime, timestamp with time zone, etc) and not just storing a string.  You are using a temporal type, right? If not, then why not?

Answer (score 1):

if you are storing the date in the database as a timestamp this should work

```
<?php echo date("d/m/Y",$row["m_date"]);?>
```

if you are storing the date in the database as a date or datetime this should work

```
<?php echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row["m_date"]));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the m_date stored in the databases? Is it a datetime object? Or a string. 
Problem with strtotime is that it isn't real good at deciphering written dates. So something like `27/2/2011` gives problems while `27/02/2011` gives no problems at all.

So there are 2 solutions:

1. Make sure all the dates that get entered into the database are of the correct format (`dd/mm/yyyy`).
2. Write a regular expression that adds a leading zero to all single characters.